# Python Numpy: How to transpose only the last several dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

For example, if I only want to transpose the last two dimensions of this array:
`a=np.random.randn(2,2,2,2,2)`, I would write something like: `a.transpose((0,1,2,4,3))`. How do I omit the leading dimensions? What are the neat and efficient methods? Thanks!

Edit, I know how to simply swap the shape and strides of the array, but I think it looks messy:

```
strides=list(a.strides)
strides[-2], strides[-1]=strides[-1], strides[-2]
a.strides= strides

shape=list(a.shape)
shape[-2], shape[-1]=shape[-1], shape[-2]
a.shape= shape
```

I'm wondering if there is a neat way of doing it.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer, but it looks like this only support swap 2 axis, what if I want to transpose the last 3 axis? are there an universal way?

Comment: If this is to me, then you could always do moveaxis multiple times.

Comment: Oh I was replying to the other answer that proposed to use np.swapaxes. On the other hand, np.moveaxis can move multiple axis at once, and support indexing from the right, that's exactly what I want! Thanks Tevien

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `np.moveaxis` method is what you want:

```
a = np.moveaxis(a, -1, -2)
```